# Impala - Does impala allow multi GROUP_CONCAT in one query

Tags: sql, impala

For example, I have a table below

```
+-----------+-------+------------+
|        Id |      a|           b|
+-----------+-------+------------+
|         1 |     6 |         20 |
|         1 |     4 |         55 |
|         1 |     9 |         56 |
|         1 |     2 |         67 |
|         1 |     7 |         80 |
|         1 |     5 |         66 |
|         1 |     3 |         33 |
|         1 |     8 |         34 |
|         1 |     1 |         52 |
```

I want the output would be like below by using Impala

```
+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------------+
|        Id |     a             |                           b |
+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------------+
|         1 | 6,4,9,2,7,5,3,8,1 | 20,55,56,67,80,66,33,34,52  |
+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

In Impala, I have used

```
SELECT Id, 
       group_concat(DISTINCT a) AS a, 
       group_concat(DISTINCT b) AS b 
FROM table GROUP BY Id
```

It will always get Syntax error. Just wondering is that we are not allowed to use multi group_concat for one query in Impala? or not allow to use multi Distinct for one query?

Comment: Are you saying that if you had only a single `GROUP_CONCAT` call, the query would run without error?  What is the exact error you get?

Comment: Yes, this is very stranger. I know previously they have issue with multi Count function: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-110. And that defect was fixed in the new release. But now it seems we are not allowed to use multi group_concat in impala. The error msg is: 'AnalysisException: all DISTINCT aggregate functions need to have the same set of parameters as group_concat(DISTINCT t.fieldvalue); deviating function: group_concat(DISTINCT acc.fieldvalue) Consider using NDV() instead of COUNT(DISTINCT) if estimated counts are acceptable.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation for `GROUP_CONCAT`](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-2-x/topics/impala_group_concat.html):

> You cannot apply the DISTINCT operator to the argument of this function.

But, as workaround, we can use two separate subqueries to find the distinct values:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT Id, GROUP_CONCAT(a) AS a
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Id, a FROM yourTable) t
    GROUP BY Id
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT Id, GROUP_CONCAT(b) AS b
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Id, b FROM yourTable) t
    GROUP BY Id
)

SELECT
    t1.Id,
    t1.a,
    t2.b
FROM cte1 t1
INNER JOIN cte2 t2
    ON t1.Id = t2.Id;
```

Comment: Hi Tim, when I am using one Distinct, it was working. `select id, group_concat(distinct a) from table group by id`

Comment: Yes, and two isn't working, so I gave you a workaround.

Comment: yes, I'll try the use of CTE and have a look. Thanks Tim

Comment: @user3651247 I'm surprised it doesn't work in Impala.  I tested your original query in MySQL, and it works without any problem.  But, I also tested my answer, and it works too.

Comment: Yes, in MySQL, it is actually working with no problem. I think this may due to Impala is still quite new, which may still have many defects in it...

Comment: Not really _defects_, it's just that asking for a group concat with distinct is a lot of work to do, and maybe they haven't gotten around to that yet.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Like for some MySQL version, we need to use STUFF to run concatenation which will cost a lot. At least, Impala engine is much faster already. lol

Comment: Hi Tim, I have tested this in Impala, this way will give lots of duplicates record after group_concat. So this is why I used `Group_Concat(Distinct a)`, but seems Impala does not support group concat with distinct for twice in one script.

Comment: This query works for the sample data you showed, and other test data which I tried myself.  What do you mean by "lots of duplicates?"  I suspect you have some other requirement which did not come across in your original question.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I found why the duplicate issue was occurred. I have used LEFT OUTER JOIN in the table with other tables. LEFT OUTER JOIN will always run before GROUP_CONCAT. So may duplicates will be produced in the Group_concat output.